# Как заставить объект вращаться по оси?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Этот код вращает мой объект по `y` оси. А как я могу поменять на `x`?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Corei7_anim : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed, tilt;
    private Vector3 target = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * tilt);
    }}
```

Comment: видимо `transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * tilt *  Time.deltaTime);` :)

Comment: начал дергаться и по "y" вращается. только как будь то ко мне летит. а должен вращаться по "x". как карусель наверно, когда смотришь на карусель.

Comment: Документация говорит  что всё должно быть ОК  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html .....может быть это не весь предоставленный код или еще где-то что-то изменяется параллельно? .... вместо tilt наверное должно быть speed ...... а то я не знаю что такое tilt в твоем случае

Comment: У вас методы .up и .right поворачивают фигуру по одной и той же оси? Или вы невнимательно переписали Rotate c комментария @АлексейШиманский ?

Comment: Это весь мой код)))
Возможно моделька не правильно настроено. когда я загрузил его он был перевернут)) и мне пришлось перевернуть по Y на 180 градусов.

Comment: 1 https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/04/0e40c144e0dc0463590d3f31072c8647.png
2 https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/04/2aa90cc672edd506acfedc151e443d5e.png

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Corei7_anim : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed, tilt;
    private Vector3 target = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
  
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * tilt);
    }}
`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195696/valera-kvip все тот же что в топике. ничего не изменился. и это весь код)

Comment: Если что вот как моделька лежит в unity http://image.prntscr.com/image/aaeabddbebc341c2a4e7c5a49e493130.png

Comment: да, но начал крутиться сверху вниз.) при значений up и down крутится как будь то руль поворачиваешь налево. При left и right крутиться сверху вниз как будь то на тебя что то летит.  Я хочу чтобы крутилась как карусель)

Comment: `transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * tilt);`
решение)

Comment: @Mr.Husky я обновил свой ответ. Ознакомьтесь

Comment: да все ок)) спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
Transform transform;

void Start()
{
    transform = GameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    // Получаем ссылку на компонент Transfrom после первого кадра
    // Start() можно заменить на Awake(), если хочется
    // Тогда будем получать ссылку до старта сцены
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward* 4f * Time.deltaTime);
    // Вращаем объект вокруг своей оси
    // Важно понимать какой вектор отвечает за ось
    // Глянем в доки. Vector3.forward- это вектор (1, 0, 0). Отлично, подходит
}
```

P.S. Со скриптом в `GetComponent()` мог немного накосячить, давно не пишу на шарпе и не работаю с Unity, но вроде всё верно. Также постоянно в `Update()` писать `transfrom.Rotate()` без взятия ссылки на компонент `Transfrom` - пример плохого кода. Потому что `transform` в Unity автоматически выполняет функцию взятия ссылки на компонент, но не сохраняет её. То есть вы выполняете лишнюю операцию каждый кадр.

Если у вас модель с неправильно настроенным вращением, то нужно использовать другие вектора. Если вам сложно понять вокруг какого вектора будет двигаться модель,вы можете нарисовать этот вектор с помощью функции `Debug.DrawRay()`

Например, так:

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.forward, Color.red);
```

Таким образом в редакторе будет отображён луч из объекта по направлению `Vector3.forward`

Документацию к `Debug.DrawRay()` можно найти [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html)

Также, чтобы не сильно париться, можно просто удочерить модель к пустому объекту и вешать скрипт уже на пустой объект, либо изначально пытаться получить родителя у объекта в скрипте, а если родителя нет, то за `Transform` вращения брать сам объект.

Но это тоже не самый лучший вариант. Гораздо лучше починить модель в каком-нибудь 3D редакторе и сделать импорт модели заново.

В любом случае, какой вариант выбирать - решать вам.

Comment: разве `transform.Translate` вращает объект вокруг оси?  ...............................`Если у вас модель с неправильно настроенным вращением, то нужно использовать другие вектора` - зачем изначально идти по неправильному пути? Для решения проблемы нужно либо импортировать её правильно, либо, на худой конец, поставить её в пустой объект так, чтоб оси совпадали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский конечно нет, спасибо, что заметили косяк, исправил. Учитывайте, я уже очень давно с Unity не работаю. `Translate()` будет двигать объект, а не вращать. По поводу смены рута и засовывания модели в пустышку - это вы, кстати, хорошо заметили, совсем забыл про такую фичу, стоит добавить в ответ. Но это в любом случае плохая реализация. Гораздо лучше отредактировать модель в каком-либо 3D редакторе и сделать импорт снова.

Answer (score -1):

Решение:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * tilt);
```

Возможные значение forward, fwd, up, down, left, right. (Так же есть one и zero но ничего не поменялось)

Comment: Это неправильное решение. `Vector3.forward`  аналогичен записи `Vector3(0, 0, 1).`, т.е. соответсвует оси Z, а не X. А значит проблема в импортированной модели, а значит для решения проблемы нужно либо импортировать её правильно, либо поставить её в пустой объект так, чтоб оси совпадали

Comment: да проблема в модели. но это решило проблему. и внизу указал возможные значение чтобы другие те кто пришли с такими же проблемами понимали что менять)

Comment: на самом деле остальные не поймут и это не решит их проблему, а только запутает, потому что они не знают, что у тебя модель неправильно импортирована. Кмк, скорее надо акцентировать на этом внимание и что только в данном случае оно решает проблему. А с норм моделями решение было еще в самом первом моём комментарии))

Comment: xD ладно хорошо сдаюсь)

Comment: @Mr.Husky да уберите вы этот ответ