# Вращение и передвижение объекта в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код вращения:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeFloat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed, tilt;
    private Vector3 target = new Vector3(0, 1.39f, 0);

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        if (transform.position == target && target.y != 0.1f)
            target.y = 0.1f;
        else if (transform.position == target && target.y == 0.1f)
            target.y = 1.39f;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * tilt);
    }
}
```

Ожидаемый результат: вращение объекта только по оси Y и не делать смещения по Z.

Фактический результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...

UPD:
Вращение во круг своей оси работает, необходимо двигать только по Y.
Движение ограничено, то есть, когда position.Y дошло до определенного значения, оно должно изменить направление.
Предполагается, что кубик должен вращаться вверх-вниз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не твой мульт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/653278/191482  ?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , нет :)

Comment: Почему бы просто не сделать это через анимацию?

Comment: В каком смысле через анимацию?

Comment: Зачем зря использовать скрипт, если это можно сделать в анимации и не использовать скрипт вообще?

Comment: `В каком смысле через анимацию?` - тебе же нужно сделать мотание объекта туда-сюда так? Плюс вращение. Залезай в анимацию объекта, добавь несколько кадров и сделай так, чтоб он с 1 по 10 кадр например ехал вправо, а с 10 по 20 - влево...Плюс вращение.......в целом это называется `tween`.

Comment: Обновил ответ, ознакомьтесь

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть следующие предположения:

У тебя обьект, видимо, находится в другом обьекте. И как следствие -- используются локальные оси вместо глобальных.
Или же ты в коде намадрил(влом разбиратся, все равно не похоже на толковое решение)

....

Сделай просто смену угла через задавание нового Rotation. Все.

На вскидку код будет что-то вроде:

```
var oldRot =  transform.position.Rotation;
transform.position.Rotation = new Quanterion(oldRot.x, oldRot.y + Time.deltaTime * speed, oldRot.z, oldRot.w)
```

не проверял и юнити запускал давно, но должно заработать, думаю.

Или же сделай что-то вроде:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    void Update() {
        Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;

        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0F);
    }
}
```

код взял с https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html

Comment: `Кроме того не имеет смысла делать Vector3.MoveTowards если это апдейт.` - можешь сказать, что это значит? а где делать MoveTowards?

Comment: я не совсем правильно написал т.к. попутал с другим методом) Его нужно использовать когда тебе нужно что бы обьект взаимодействовал с другими обьектами(коллайдеры) -- что в твоем примере не нужно, а так же когда нужно двигать обьект от точки к точке(двигать! А не поворачивать!!!). А для поворачивания(что бы было с взаимодействием коллайдерами, что тебе так же нафиг не нужно в даном примере) нужно использовать Vector3.RotateTowards

Comment: это **не мой** случай...

Answer (score 1):

Логика должна быть какой-то такой

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 6.5f, moveSpeed = 8f, range = 10f; // скорость вращения, скорость перемещения, допустимый размах для передвижения
    Vector3 startPosition; // Vector3 начала координат
    Transform cube; // private переменная для хранения ссылки на Transform объекта
    Vector3 direction = Vector3.up; // переменная для стартового направления движения
    // можно сделать Vector3 публичной переменной и задавать нужно направление в инспекторе

    void Start()
    {
        cube = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>(); // получаем ссылку на компонент Trnasform
        startPosition = cube.position; // запоминаем стартовые координаты
    }

    void Update()
    {
        cube.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // вращаем куб вокруг своей оси
        cube.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed); // двигаем куб вверх-вниз

        if (cube.position.y <= startPosition.y - range) // если мы дошли до пика startPosition.y - range
        {
            direction = Vector3.up; // сменяем направление движения
        }

        else if (cube.position.y >= startPosition.y + range) // если мы дошли до пика startPosition.y + range
        {
            direction = Vector3.down; // сменяем направление движения
        }
    }
}
```

Также можно двигать объект не только вниз вверх, но и куда угодно в пределах размаха. Для этого нам поможет функция `Vector3.Distance()`. Чтобы рандомно задавать направление, можно немного изменить код и дописать функцию, которая будет это делать за нас. Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 6.5f, moveSpeed = 8f, range = 10f; // скорость вращения, скорость перемещения, допустимый размах для передвижения
    Vector3 startPosition; // Vector3 начала координат
    Transform cube; // private переменная для хранения ссылки на Transform объекта
    Vector3 direction;// вектор направления
    float x, y, z; // переменные для вектора направления


    void Start()
    {
        cube = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>(); // получаем ссылку на компонент Trnasform
        startPosition = cube.position; // запоминаем стартовые координаты
        GetDirection(); // задаём случайное направление
    }

    void Update()
    {
        cube.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // вращаем куб вокруг своей оси
        cube.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed); // двигаем куб по заданному вектору direction

        if (Vector3.Distance(cube.position, startPosition) >= range) // если разница векторов от начальной точки до текущей позиции больше чем размах
        {
            GetDirection(); // задаём случайное направление
        }
    }

    // так мы задаём случайное направление
    void GetDirection()
    {
        x = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        y = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        z = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);

        direction = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

А с помощью `enum` мы можем сделать скрипт более универсальным, выбирая как нам передвигать тот или иной объект. Ниже идёт улучшенная версия данного скрипта с доработками.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 4f, moveSpeed = 6f, range = 5.5f; // скорость вращения, скорость перемещения, допустимый размах для передвижения
    Vector3 startPosition; // Vector3 начала координат
    Transform root; // ссылка на Transform, который будет двигаться
    Transform child; // ссылка на Transfrom, который будет вращаться
    public Vector3 direction;// вектор направления

    public enum DirectionType { UpDown, LeftRight, ForwardBackward, Randomly, OwnDirection }
    public DirectionType directionType = DirectionType.Randomly;
    // типы движения. Что может вызывать вопросы, так это Randomly и OwnDirection
    // Randomly - случайное передвижение, OwnDirection - свой вектор движения


    void Start()
    {
        StartPreparations();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        child.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // вращаем куб вокруг своей оси
        root.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed); // двигаем куб

        //если вышли за пределы размаха
        if (Vector3.Distance(root.position, startPosition) >= range) InverseDirection(); // инверсируем движение

        // в случае с рандомным движением инверсия будет придавать случайное направление, потому что объект
        // не только движется, но и вращается вокруг своей оси, а движем мы не родителя объекта, а сам объект (см. StartPreparations())
    }

    // так мы задаём случайное направление
    void GetDirection()
    {
        direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f));
    }

    // так инверсируем направление
    void InverseDirection()
    {
        direction *= -1;
    }

    // начальные приготовления
    void StartPreparations()
    {
        child = GetComponent<Transform>(); // получаем ссылку на трансформ, который будет вращаться

        if (directionType == DirectionType.Randomly) root = child; // если вращаемся рандомно, то root'ом должен быть child

        else
        {
            root = child.root; // получаем ссылку на родителя child
            if (directionType != DirectionType.UpDown)
            {
                if (root == child)
                {
                    // для движения вверх вниз необязательно иметь родителя, а для рандомного он вовсе не нужен
                    // поэтому если движение не Randomly и не UpDown
                    // и при этом root == child создаём пустой объект с координатами child.position и делаем его родителем child
                    Debug.LogWarning("Опять пустышку за тебя создавать?!");
                    GameObject rootGO = new GameObject();
                    rootGO.transform.position = child.position;
                    child.SetParent(rootGO.transform);
                    root = child.root;
                }
            }
        }

        startPosition = root.position; // запоминаем стартовые координаты
        rotationSpeed *= 10; // усиляем скорость вращения

        if (directionType == DirectionType.Randomly) GetDirection(); // если движемся рандомно, задаём случайное направление
        else if (directionType == DirectionType.UpDown) direction = Vector3.up; // если вверх-вниз - задаём направление вверх
        else if (directionType == DirectionType.LeftRight) direction = Vector3.left; // если влево-вправо - задавём вектор движения влево
        else if (directionType == DirectionType.ForwardBackward) direction = Vector3.forward; // если вперёд-назад, то задаём вектор вперёд
        // ещё остаётся OwnDirection, но приравнивать вектор к самому себе как-то глупо
    }
}
```

Учитывайте, что динамически снизить значение `range` не получится. Его можно будет только увеличить. Если в инспекторе снизить значение `range` после старта сцены, то куб скорее всего зависнет в одном положении. Чтобы динамически уменьшить значение `range` нужно будет сделать эту переменную публичной, либо создать метод и посылать сообщение кубу через `SendMessage()`, а также сбрасывать положение куба до стартовой позиции, либо `Lerp()`'ить, если нужна красота и плавность.

Comment: вместо двух условий по смене направления не проще ли написать чуть по длиннее но по-короче `if (cube.position.y <= startPosition.y - range || cube.position.y >= startPosition.y + range) { direction *= -1; }` ??? это ж классика умножение на -1

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так бы сниппет был очень длинным. Да и если что, можно же переписать. И, вообще, чудо, что я смог написать такое без ошибок) Давно с Unity не работаю, как и давно не пишу на `C#` и писал код в `sublime` на linux.

Comment: @J. Defenses ну что, помогло?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский обновил ответ